# new class inserted in while : Can I do that?

Tags: php, class, while-loop

I need to display different product inside my page. I try to develop by a class (I am novice) but I am sur is not correct to insert $OSCOM_ProductB2B  = new ProductsB2B($products['products_id']) inside a while. no ?

Thank you.

```
class ProductsB2B {

  protected $id;

  public function __construct($products_id) {
    global $OSCOM_PDO;

      $Qproducts = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select p.products_id,
                                               p.orders_view
                                        from :table_products p,
                                             :table_products_description pd
                                        where p.products_status = :products_status
                                        and p.products_id = :products_id
                                        and pd.products_id = p.products_id
                                        and pd.language_id = :language_id
                                        and orders_view = :orders_view
                                       ');

      $Qproducts->bindValue(':products_status',  '1' );
      $Qproducts->bindInt(':products_id',   $products_id);
      $Qproducts->bindInt(':language_id',   (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] );
      $Qproducts->execute();

      $products = $Qproducts->fetch();

      $this->id = $products['products_id'];
  }

    Private function setProductsMinQuantityShoppingCart() {
      global $OSCOM_PDO, $OSCOM_Customer;

        $products_id = osc_get_prid($this->id);
        $QminOrderQty = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select products_min_qty_order
                                             from :table_products
                                             where products_id = :products_id
                                           ');
        $QminOrderQty->bindInt(':products_id',$products_id );

        $QminOrderQty->execute();
        $min_order_qty_values = $QminOrderQty->fetch();

        $min_order_qty = $min_order_qty_values['products_min_qty_order'];

       return $min_order_qty;
     }

    Public function getProductsMinQuantityShoppingCart() {
      return $this->setProductsMinQuantityShoppingCart();
    }
} // end class
```

my files to display the product

```
   $products_query_raw = "select p.products_id
                          from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . "
                          where p.products_status = '1' 
                          and p.products_id = pd.products_id 
                          "

             $products_split = new splitPageResults($products_query_raw, MODULE_PRODUCTS_NEW_MAX_DISPLAY);
            $products_query = osc_db_query($products_split->sql_query);

              while ($products = osc_db_fetch_array($products_query)) {

                $OSCOM_ProductB2B  = new ProductsB2B($products['products_id']); // ===> there I amnot sure,it could make a problem ????

                echo MIN_QTY_ORDER_PRODUCT  . $OSCOM_ProductB2B->getProductsMinQuantityShoppingCart();
              }
```

Comment: No i think it's the worst way of doing so. what if your loop is executed 10 times or more ?

Comment: How to resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You're making different objects from one single class in a loop. you're loop fetches data from your db what if you have a table with 100 row ? you make 100 objects of one single class ? Although you pass different variable each time but that's not reasonable. put it out of the loop. you don't need to pass vars to the constructor of your class. define a method and pass them each time to the method. Also i suggest you download some PHP shop scripts from the net and see how they are dealing with the information.

Don't hesitate to ask further Question.

Good luck